# Codeigniter custom library initialization issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, constructor, codeigniter-3, libraries

I am using codeigniter for a while but today I'm facing a strange issue, maybe someone would have an explanation :)
When i'm initializing custom libraries in a controller like that

**Main controller**

```
class Tests extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->library(['lib_wishlists', 'lib_basket']);
    }
}
```

**Lib_wishlists**

```
class Lib_wishlists
{
    /**
     * @var CI_Controller
     */
    protected CI_Controller $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library('lib_basket');
        $this->CI->load->database();

        $this->initWishlist();
    }

    public function use_wishlist_as_basket(array $where = []): ReturnObject
    {
        /** ERROR HERE Line 386 **/
        $addObj = $this->CI->lib_basket->add_product_checks(...);
    }
}
```

**Lib_basket**

```
class Lib_basket
{
    /**
     * @var CI_Controller
     **/
    protected CI_Controller $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library('lib_wishlists');

        $this->init_basket();
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function init_basket()
    {
        if (empty($this->CI->session->userdata('basket')))
        {
            if ($this->CI->auth->logged_in())
            {
                $this->CI->lib_wishlists->use_wishlist_as_basket(...);

            } else $this->CI->session->set_userdata('basket', []);
        }
    }
}
```

**Error backtrace**

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Tests::$lib_basket

Filename: libraries/Lib_wishlists.php

Line Number: 386

Backtrace:

File: /Users/maximephilippe/Sites/localhost/VIPSTORE/application/libraries/Lib_wishlists.php
Line: 386
Function: _error_handler

File: /Users/maximephilippe/Sites/localhost/VIPSTORE/application/libraries/Lib_basket.php
Line: 47
Function: use_wishlist_as_basket

File: /Users/maximephilippe/Sites/localhost/VIPSTORE/application/libraries/Lib_basket.php
Line: 33
Function: init_basket

File: /Users/maximephilippe/Sites/localhost/VIPSTORE/application/controllers/Tests.php
Line: 18
Function: library

File: /Users/maximephilippe/Sites/localhost/vipstore/index.php
Line: 322
Function: require_once
```

If anyone has an idea i would be very grateful ;)
The problem is because init_basket() is called from the constructor, if I comment out the line $this->init_basket() in lib_basket and I call it from the Tests controller I don't have the issue, look like the libraries loading is going in a wrong way

Comment: Not sure, but aren't you loading $lib_basket into the main Instance of CI? The error message says you're trying to access a property of Tests, which hasn't been set. In your __construct function within the class Tests, you merely load $lib_basket into CI instead of making it a property of Tests. Also, the error is on line 386 of Lib_wishlists.php, which is a line of code that you haven't shared in your question.

Comment: Sorry you are right the peace of code (line 386) where i put ERROR HERE was actually in lib_wishlist,
I understand your point and I came to the same conclusion, but in the lib_wishlist constructor there is 
```$this->CI->load->library('lib_basket');```
in case it is not loaded and even in lib_basket there is also
```$this->CI->load->library('lib_wishlist');```
So normally it is loaded in $this->CI which is the same instance of the main CI ?
How would you correct it ?

Comment: You're correct, if you use `$this->CI->load`, you're loading the library into the main instance of CI, which is the same instance. Every controller that is loaded will automatically receive a property ->CI which will refer to the main instance.   I talked this over with my colleague, and he pointed out that the class names are UCFirst, but you load them using lowercase names. Could you verify if this could solve the problem? Otherwise we'll keep on trying to help :)